# check if instance inherited from generic or non generic version of a class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, casting

so I have inheritance chain like this:

```
class a : {}
class a<T> : {}
class b: a<int> {}
class c: a {}
```

and I need to check if instance (let's say `var inst = new b()`) inherited from `a<>` or from `a` only.

however, nothing of standard `IsAssignableFrom`, `IsSubclassOf`, `IsInstanceOfType`, `is` don't fit.

What is a proper way to do this?

*UPD1: Inheritance chain could be deeper than 1 level*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A instance of class b is not derived from `a<T>`, but from `a<int>`, the two are different types.

```
var type = inst.GetType();
var result = false;

while (type != typeof(object))
{
    type = type.BaseType;
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(a<>))
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}

//check result
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is *not* inherited from `a<>`, it is inherited from `a<int>`. However, you can check by reflection whether the generic type definition of the base class is `a<>`:

```
type t = typeof(b).BaseType;
return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(a<>);
```

Comment: this will not working, because b isn't generic class. It's inherited from generic. And using BaseType also not an option, since iheritance chain could be deeper.

Comment: @silent_coder that's why he wrote `.BaseType`. This should work fine

Comment: inheritance could be deeper than one level and you normally don't know how deep is it. It's ofcourse could be possible to go down for the initial class, but I think there should be something more elegant.

Comment: @silent_coder: It was just an example for the problem. Of course no one cares how deep the inheritance is. The OP now knows he should use the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method and that's the point. But I see that Danny has already implemented a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

With your update (more inheritance levels), you could have this:

```
public static bool IsGenericA(object instance)
{
    Type t = instance.GetType();
    while(t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType != typeof(object))
      t = t.BaseType;
    return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(a<>);
}

public static bool IsNonGenericA(object instance)
{
    Type t = instance.GetType();
    while(t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType != typeof(object))
      t = t.BaseType;
    return t == typeof(a);
}
```

[See it in action in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpQeeg)

Should work for any levels as long as the base is `a` or `a<something>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that you have this hierarchy:

```
class a { }
class a<T> : a { }
class b : a<int> { }
class c : a { }
```

you need to explore inheritance tree to get base generic types and test their generic type definitions. But if you looking for some generic-purpose solution, you have to take into account interface implementation case.

E.g., if your hierarchy will be rewritten like this:

```
interface a { }
interface a<T> : a { }
class b : a<int> { }
class c : a { }
```

this will "break" inheritance tree traversal, because base type of `b` will be `System.Object` instead of `a<T>`. That is, inheritance and interface implementations are two different things.

I'd implement it this way:

```
internal static class TypeExtensions
{
    private static bool IsInheritedFromGenericTypeDefinition(Type type, Type baseType)
    {
        do
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseType)
                return true;

            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        while (type != null);

        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsInheritedFrom(this Type type, Type baseType)
    {
        if (baseType.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            if (!type.IsInterface && baseType.IsInterface)
            {
                do
                {
                    // since baseType is an interface, and source type is not,
                    // we can't test inheritance tree anymore;
                    // instead, we have to obtain implemented interfaces and test them
                    var implementedInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
                    if (implementedInterfaces.Any(intf => IsInheritedFromGenericTypeDefinition(intf, baseType)))
                        return true;

                    type = type.BaseType;
                }
                while (type != null);

                return false;
            }
            else
                return IsInheritedFromGenericTypeDefinition(type, baseType);
        }

        return baseType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

Results:

> a  ->      a<>     =       True
>
> b       ->      a<>     =       True
>   b       ->      a  =       True
>   b       ->      a       =       True
>
> c       ->      a       =       True
>   c       ->      a<>     =       False

Answer (score 0):

how about typeOf()  ? you can get parent classes using this

Answer (score 0):

```
class a : {}
class a<T> : {}
```

I'm sorry, but in C# `a` and `a<T>` are completely different. The fact that they both start with the letter `a` is a coincidence.

So to tell the difference, you can use the [is operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

```
 if (inst is a)
 {
    // derived from a
 }
 else 
 {
    // not derived from a
 }
```